# dnSpy doesn't decompile async/await method as it has been written

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await, .net-5

dbSpy v6.1.8
asp .net core app on .net5

In dnSpy's settings there is option **Decompile async methods (async/await)**.
I assumed this option influence on how async methods should be decompiled. In one case it should be something like this:

```
public static Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Program.<Main>d__6 <Main>d__ = new Program.<Main>d__6();
    <Main>d__.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Create();
    <Main>d__.args = args;
    <Main>d__.<>1__state = -1;
    <Main>d__.<>t__builder.Start<Program.<Main>d__6>(ref <Main>d__);
    return <Main>d__.<>t__builder.Task;
}
```

In other something like this:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

But despite value of this option it always shows method like in first example. I tried relaunch dnSpy, clear all assemblies and reload them, but all in vain.

Is it possible to force dbSpy shows method similar to second example?

Comment: Have you tried [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy). Either way, the reconstruction of the original code is based on patterns and might not always be possible or accurate.

Comment: I tell about dnSpy because I would want to have debug ability. But I would want to debug app with more "humanity" code.